# The use of the squeeze theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to understand why we use the squeeze theorem and why is it even theorem  because is it very obvious.In general, if the denominator in a sequence dominates the numerator and it is continuously increasing, then surely  all elements of the sequence will approach the same limit?

Comment: Define "obvious"

Comment: Squeezing is nice when doing estimates, say on integrals. It allows us to deduce the limit when we can trap a sequence between two sequences with a common limit.

Comment: What is the "denominator of a sequence"?..."highest power" etc.? I don't know what theorem you are referring to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many theorems that seem obvious, but that doesn't mean that we can just hand-waive away the necessity of a proof.  Often the most obvious ones turn out to be the most difficult to prove.

A classic application of the squeeze theorem is to use:

$\cos x\le \frac {\sin x}{x} \le 1$

to prove $\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {\sin x}{x} = 1$ which may be difficult to prove by a more direct method.

Comment: E.g., the Jordan curve theorem seems *extremely* obvious ...

Comment: Very good example. Thank you.